# Cannot create type as specific number when number is in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, variables, math

I want to create a type that can be only 1 or root 2.  This works:

```js
type OneOrRootTwo = 1 | 1.4142135623730951;
```

But when I try to use `Math.SQRT2`, or any variable reference to the numeric value of root 2, I get an error.  For example:

```js
type OneOrRootTwo = 1 | Math.SQRT2; // Math is a type, not a namespace error

const root2 = 1.4142135623730951;
type OneOrRootTwo = 1 | root2; // root2 is a value but is being used a type error
```

#### [Typescript playground demonstrating the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAnASgezcAKgdzVAXigEYoAfEgOgBYBuAKHoGM04BnYKJDYAJkKgBZAIbAAFpQDKARRRZeDeqEhQAcpgDqaJAGsAlnADmpIqQojxU2fIbLo64Ft0HD-U+S48FQA)

In my code I want to be able to reference the root of 2 with to a uniform number of decimal places.  I don't want to have to write 1.4142135623730951 every time.  Why am I getting a type error when trying to use Math.SQRT2, or the value as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting a type error when trying to use Math.SQRT2, or the value as a variable?

In order to use a value as a type, you need to use `typeof`:

```
type OneOrRootTwo = 1 | typeof root2;
```

However, this won't give you what you want, because typescript infers a numeric literal as a `number` instead of the explicit value of that number, which makes `typeof root2` equal to `number`. If you want it to be typed as the numeric literal `1.4142135623730951`, you can use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which narrows the type to the literal value:

```
const root2 = 1.4142135623730951 as const;
type OneOrRootTwo = 1 | typeof root2; // 1 | 1.4142135623730951
```

---

In regards to Math.SQRT2, the type definition has it typed as a `number`, so you won't be able to use it as a literal type unless you typecast it:

```
const x: OneOrRootTwo = Math.SQRT2 as 1.4142135623730951;
```

If you're doing that, you're better off just exporting your own set of constant values like `root2`.

Comment: Perfect.  I knew `as const` was going to figure in somehow, but I couldn't put my finger on it. Thank you sir